# excel vba selecting columns

Tags: excel, vba, select

I want to select a range of entire excel columns. Is it possible to select them with this expression?

```
range(cells(rowindex, columnindex),cells(rowindex,columnindex)).Select
```

So far it didn't really work out. I have to change the format and width for them.

best, US

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Range("b2:f5").Columns.ColumnWidth = 5
```

or

```
Range(Columns(6), Columns(9)).ColumnWidth = 15
```

By the way, you don't need to Select for acting on a range. That just slows down your macro and make it longer to read.